# Where does Firefox store javascript/HTML localStorage?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, local-storage, web-storage

I have made an advanced functional prototype of a simple web application, and delays have pushed this into the position of going "live".

At the moment, it just uses JavaScript's `localStorage` facility to keep track of what's happening, but due to paranoia, we don't want it to be corrupted causing loss of data (it certainly feels a bit sketchy never talking to a server).

Where does Firefox keep its `localStorage` database (I think it's SQLite, but I just can't find it)?

Comment: this Q&A may be helpful, though not about firefox specifically http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23587074/access-web-storage-or-indexeddb-from-outside-the-browser-in-android

Comment: For a live web app, I'm guessing you have end users, not programmers, inputting data. So rather than have them find and backup a specific file on their machine, why not add JavaScipt to the app that periodically syncs their localStorage contents to the server?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> The DOM storage data is stored in the `webappsstore.sqlite` file in the profile 
>   folder.

[`§ localStorage`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage#localStorage)

Comment: The profile folder is located in `%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\​`, named something like `321edcba.default`, and within it, there’s the `webappsstore.sqlite`.

Comment: Check out @Ethan's answer to see the up to date location in `storage/default`.

Answer (score 14):

On Mac OS X, the `webappsstore.sqlite` is located under `~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/xxxxxxxx.default/` (where xxxxxxxx is random according to [Firefox Profile Tutorial](http://www.borngeek.com/firefox/profile-tutorial/) ).

I used the [Command Line Shell For SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html) to look around.  Assuming www.example.com was a real site and the only site using localstorage, you can run these commands:

```
$ sqlite3 webappsstore.sqlite
sqlite> .tables
webappsstore2
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE webappsstore2 (scope TEXT, key TEXT, value TEXT, secure INTEGER, owner TEXT);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX scope_key_index ON webappsstore2(scope, key);
sqlite> select * from webappsstore2;
moc.elpmaxe.www.:http:80|stringkey|value|0|
moc.elpmaxe.www.:http:80|jsonkey|{"key","value"}|0|
sqlite> .exit
```

See [How is HTML5 WebStorage data physically stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9669184/how-is-html5-webstorage-data-physically-stored/14887525#14887525) for the Chrome storage location.  Chrome uses individual sqlite files per hostname and protocol, where Firefox uses the reversed hostname and protocol in the scope column.

See [Where the sessionStorage and localStorage stored?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634058/where-the-sessionstorage-and-localstorage-stored/15711210#15711210) for the Opera storage location.  Opera uses an XML index file and individual XML files for the Base64 encoded data.

Comment: Check out @Ethan's answer to see the up to date location on macOS.

Answer (score 1):

As of [LSNG](https://wiki.mozilla.org/DOM/Workers-Storage/projects/lsng), local storage is also found in the profile directory under `storage/default/`.

Comment: Thanks! The full path on macOS is `/Users/user/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/….default-release/storage/default/ls/data.sqlite` and the permissions don't allow opening it from there so make a copy to read it (it has no password).