# backbone.js and localstorage - system storage place

Tags: cordova, backbone.js, ripple, backbone-local-storage

I'm developing a mobile application using `Cordova` and `Backbone.js` with `Backbone localStorage Adapter` ([link](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage)).
I'm using `ripple` emulator to test the application using the browser on my computer.

I'd like to know what folder on my OS does Backbone localstorege use to store the information.

Thanks

Comment: In browser you can write `localstorage` in console to see the current items in localstorage.

Comment: Refer this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079075/where-does-firefox-store-javascript-html-localstorage/14901354