# Why there is no webappsstore.sqlite file in the Firefox profiles folder?

Tags: javascript, firefox, local-storage

I would like to read local storage saved by Firefox. From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079075/where-does-firefox-store-javascript-html-localstorage) I found out that the local storage has to be in the

```
\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\????????.default
```

folder. But in my case it is not there. I thought that maybe Firefox disable JavaScripts or does not accept cookies. But it does not seem to be the case.

So, where can I find local storage created by Firefox?

Comment: You mean the default profile or the sqlite database is missing? What's your FF version?

Comment: The version that I use is 41.0.1

Comment: I think I need sqlite databases. I want to see the content of local storage.

Answer (score 3):

Try opening `about:support` (by typing it in the address bar) and then click "Show Folder" under Application Basics -> Profile Folder.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Windows 7 check this path:

> AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\webappsstore.sqlite

Comment: Thank you! I just need to add that in the `AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\``I have `*.default` folder and there (in this sub-folder) I do have `webappsstore.sqlite`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your profile folder is wrong folder.You can find profile folder, by use path variable `"appdata"` like `"%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles"` in wondows os.Answer above is correct too.In this folder will be other folder like `"xxxxxxxx.default"`, in that folder you can find sqlite file.
Read this [articale](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder) about profile folder location.